# If $A$ is diagonalisable, why $\dim\big(\ker(A-\lambda I)\big)=\dim\big(\ker(PAP^{-1}-\lambda I)\big)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ a matrix $n\times n$. If $A$ is diagonalizable, why $$\dim\big(\ker(A-\lambda I)\big)=\dim\big(\ker(PAP^{-1}-\lambda I)\big)$$
whenever $P$ is invertible ?

This result indeed makes sense, but I'm unable to prove it.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: Hint: $A$ and $PAP^{-1}$, with $P$ invertible, have the same eigenvalues...

Comment: @Martigan: To have same eigenvalue is not sufficient, e.g. $$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\quad \text{and}\quad \begin{pmatrix}1&2\\0&1\end{pmatrix},$$ have same eigen value, but the dimension of there eigenspace associated to the eigenvalue 1 are not the same.

Comment: @Surb Clearly this is not enough... But it was only a hint, not the solution. The idea was also to make him work. They have the same eigenspaces as well, but it was really too muc information IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $PAP^{-1}-\lambda I = P(A - \lambda I) P^{-1}$, so that $A-\lambda I$ and $PAP^{-1}-\lambda I$ are similar matrices. Hence their kernels are isomorphic, and in particular, they have the same dimension.

This follows from the following general lemma:

> **Lemma.** Let $M$ be an $n \times n$ matrix and let $P$ be an invertible $n \times n$ matrix. There is a linear isomorphism $\ker M \overset{\cong}{\longrightarrow} \ker PMP^{-1}$.

To prove this, note that the map $v \mapsto Pv$ is well-defined (since if $Av=0$ then $PAP^{-1}Pv=0$), linear and invertible, hence is a linear isomorphism.

Setting $M=A-\lambda I$ gives the result you desire.

Diagonalisability of $A$ was not a necessary hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

This is just another way to state that similar matrices have the same dimension eigenspaces.

To prove it we first note that $=PAP^{-1} - \lambda I = P(A- \lambda I)P^{-1}$.

Then we use the fact that $P$ is invertible to get that $PBP^{-1}v=0 \iff BP^{-1}v = 0 \iff P^{-1}v \in \ker(B)$.

Finally we use again that $P$ is invertible to deduce $ \dim (P^{-1} (\ker(B)) ) = \dim(\ker(B))$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $PAP^{-1} - \lambda I = P(A - \lambda I)P^{-1}$. Thus, if $\{v_1,...v_n\}$ is base for $Ker(A - \lambda I)$,since $P$ is isomorphism,  $\{Pv_1,...Pv_n\}$ is L.I.. That implies  $dim(Ker(PAP^{-1} - \lambda I)) \geq dim(Ker(A - \lambda I))$. By other side, if $\{w_1,...,w_m\}$ is base of $Ker(PAP^{-1} - \lambda I)$ that implies that $(A - \lambda I)P^{-1}w_i = 0$, for $i=1,...,m$ and therefore  $\{P^{-1}w_1,...,P^{-1}w_m\} \subset Ker(A - \lambda I)$  and because $\{P^{-1}w_1,...,P^{-1}w_m\}$ is L.I., we have that $dim(Ker(PAP^{-1} - \lambda I)) \leq dim(Ker(A - \lambda I))$.